# Magento 2: how to get Custom Options in custom product list on detail page?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, related-products, product-links

This is my Custom Collection, I want **custom options** in this collection below the price.
[image]
[image]

I have **custom product collection** like **related, upsell products,** the collection is properly displaying on the product page. now I want to display **custom options** (same as swatches) in that collection using XML.
How can I make it possible?

I tried as below but not Working.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
      </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
    </block>
</block>
```

Comment: your question is totally unclear. can you provide an example?

Comment: @Marius i updated my question, Now can you please help me out with this.
Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @FenaShah you got it fixed? if yes please suggest Im also facing issue

Comment: @Pramod yes i solved it. tell me where you're getting an issue? maybe i can help you.

Comment: @FenaShah Yes, I need help on it. By programmatically I displayed the options. But now if I change the options its not changing the price

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112025/magento-custom-option-in-list please join here @FenaShah